# Javascript timed slideshow not working in the least

Tags: javascript, slideshow

And it's saddening. Some background, I'm new to Javascript and this is my first application of in life, and since plowing halfway through half a Javascript textbook in two days. It's an external file that's linked to at the end of my HTML. If any more is required, please ask and I'll do my best to provide.

```
var slide = document.getElementById("slide");

setInterval(slideshow.changeSrc, 5000);

var slideshow = {
    changeSrc : function() {    
        if(slide.src === "./images/s1.png"){
            slide.src = "./images/s2.png";
        }
        else if(slide.src === "./images/s2.png"){
            slide.src = "./images/s3.png";
        }
        else{
            slide.src = "./images/s1.png";
        }
    }
}
slide.addEventListener("load", slideshow.changeSrc, false);
```

Comment: is setInterval(slideshow.changeSrc, 5000); correct? shouldn't be slide.changeSrc instead?

Comment: This doesn't really answer your question, but typically you probably don't want to approach your slideshow this way. Generally speaking, it is best practice (for semantics and non-JS fallback) to have all the slides in your HTML (rather than dynamically adding/removing the img src attribute) then use the JS to dynamically hide/move them. I would recommend picking a good slideshow plugin and using that and/or reviewing how it works and building your own based on that inspiration. Good luck!

Comment: will account for and test! Would still like more input as to why this doesn't work itself, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `src` property is the result of the browser resolving the URL you give it. Do not use it for comparisons. In addition, only the window and certain elements such as images or scripts have `load` events. Try this:

Instead, why not just keep track of an index?

```
(function() {
  var id = 0, slide = document.getElementById('slide');
  setInterval(function() {
    id++;
    slide.src = "images/s"+id+".png";
    id %= 3;
  },5000);
})();
```

Comment: I will try that. That actually does sound alot simpler. I'll use it in tandem with loading and hiding all my images and just making them visible. Here's hoping it works. Thank you!

Comment: It worked! And in an effort to keep things more semantic, I'll add the slide images and hide them with positioning -nods- Thank you all here for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are trying to achive:

```
var slide = document.getElementById("slide");
var slideshow = {
    changeSrc : function() {    
        setTimeout(function() {
            slide.src = 'http://lorempixel.com/100/100';
        }, 1000);
    }
}
slide.addEventListener("load", slideshow.changeSrc, false);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Bs4gM/